# How do I retain the new background colour of a jlabel after it has been clicked and to make it go back to default on a second click?

Tags: java, swing

I want my jLabel component to have a different background colour when clicked. I have actually written my code for the background colour to change but I need it to retain the new colour after the click and go back to default on a second click. I need help on this.

```
private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    jLabel1.setOpaque(true); 
    jLabel1.setBackground(Color.orange); 
} 
private void jLabel1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    jLabel1.setBackground(Color.white); 
    jLabel1.setOpaque(false); 
} 
private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    jLabel1.setBackground(Color.green);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the command in `Mouse Clicked or pressed event` 
and you need to set the `JLable setOpaque`  to `true` otherwise the background is not going to be  painted because the default of `opaque` is `false` for `JLabel`.

i.e

```
  private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        jLabel1.setOpaque(true);
        jLabel1.setBackground(Color.red);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have actually done this. It is working but the background colour is not retained. I need it such that after a first click, the background color changes and remains that way, on a second click, it goes back to default. I am thinking this can be done in the ActionPerformed event.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a boolean that stores the state of the button

```
boolean isClicked = false;
```

And then in your action listener, check it's value, update the labels then make it the opposite of what it was

```
if(isClicked)
{
    label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    isClicked = false;
}
else
{
    label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    isClicked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I retain the new background colour of a jlabel after it has been clicked and to make it go back to default on a second click?

There are many ways to do it, but the ultimate concept is similar. You just need to keep a record of the new background colour in a variable.

In this case, I used 2 variables to retain the colour `oldColor` and `newColor`.

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel{  //Not necessary must be a JPanel. For e.g. only

    private Color oldColor;
    private Color newColor;
    private JLabel lbl;
    private JButton btn;

    //Constructors, initializations, getters, setters not shown

    public void init(){
        lbl.setOpaque(true);
        btn = new JButton("Click to switch color");
        btn.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        oldColor = lbl.getBackground();  //can be any color you want
        newColor = Color.GREEN;          //can be any color you want
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvet e){
            if(lbl.getBackground().equals(oldColor))
                lbl.setBackground(newColor);
            else
                lbl.setBackground(oldColor);
        }
    }        
}
```

If you have more colours, you can always use an array, an ArrayList or any other data structure which is suitable.